# sql find value less than some value

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables
Now, I need to find for each quarter, the number of courses with fewer than 5 students (but at least one student) enrolled that quarter.
What I have is

```
student (sid);
course (cid);
record (sid, cid, qtr, year, grade);

insert into record values ('A_001', 'CSE105', 'F', 2015, 3);
insert into record values ('A_001', 'CSE132A', 'F', 2015, 4);

insert into record values ('A_001', 'CSE132B', 'F', 2016, 1);
insert into record values ('A_002', 'CSE132B', 'F', 2016, 4);
insert into record values ('A_003', 'CSE132B', 'F', 2016, 2);
insert into record values ('A_004', 'CSE132A', 'F', 2016, 2);
insert into record values ('A_005', 'CSE132A', 'F', 2016, 3);
insert into record values ('A_002', 'CSE107', 'F', 2016, 4);
insert into record values ('A_003', 'CSE107', 'F', 2016, 4);
insert into record values ('A_005', 'CSE107', 'F', 2016, 2);



insert into record values ('A_002', 'CSE105', 'W', 2017, 4);
insert into record values ('A_003', 'CSE105', 'W', 2017, 3);
insert into record values ('A_004', 'CSE105', 'W', 2017, 3);
insert into record values ('A_005', 'CSE105', 'W', 2017, 2);
insert into record values ('A_006', 'CSE105', 'W', 2017, 1);
insert into record values ('A_004', 'CSE132B', 'W', 2017, 4);
insert into record values ('A_005', 'CSE132B', 'W', 2017, 2);
```

The result I want to see

```
qtr year num
 F  2015  2
 F  2016  3
 W  2017  1
```

But what I got is show the quarters which amount of class are less than 5. I think I only need to count for each quarter, the same class shows less than 5 times, does anyone have a idea how to do it, thank you so much

Comment: Just add `class_id` to the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `class_id` to the query.

```
select r.cid, r.qtr,r.year,count(*) as num
from record r
group by r.cid, r.qtr,r.year
having num <5
```

if you just want the count of classes, not all their IDs, put it into a subquery and count them:

```
SELECT qtr, year, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    select r.cid, r.qtr,r.year,count(*) as num
    from record r
    group by r.cid, r.qtr,r.year
    having num <5
) AS subquery
GROUP BY qtr, year
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c015b5/3)

Comment: "the number of courses with fewer than 5 students" - I guess you need to count the number of resulting rows using a subquery.

Comment: The one you give me show how many class for each quarter, but the one I want is to show for each quarter, how many classes duplicate less than 5 times

Comment: That's what `having num < 5` does in the subquery. So it's only counting the classes with less than 5 students in the outer query.

Comment: for example, if I have two different classes in Fall 2012, class 1 and class 2 and I have 7 classes in Winter 2013, which are two class 1 and five class 2, what I want to see is     F, 2012, 2 and W, 2013, 1, because there are five class 2 in Winter 2017, so it will not count. I hope I make that clearly, thank you for helping me

Comment: For duplicate classes for each quarter, I only count once, unless the number of duplicate is >=5

Comment: Could you post the sample data and expected result in the question, and make a sqlfiddle? I'm having trouble understanding from your description.

Comment: I edited the question with more detail, could you see if it is helpful, thank you

Comment: I fixed a syntax error and the names of the columns. It works as desired, see the sqlfiddle demo.